# unable to set values of select tag in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I had created a select tag in html(SelectTest.html) with some values.What i'm trying to do is after selecting any value from select tag, i need the page to be refreshed and pass the selected option as parameter to url.

Then i need to set this as selected value once the page is refreshed. I'm not sure whether this problem is related to jQuery mobile.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var param = window.location.search;

    if(param)
    {


      var indx = param.indexOf("=");

        //now get the value of selected type

        aval =param.substring(indx+1);

        $("#lang").val(aval);
    }   

    $("#lang").change(function(){

        var sel = $(this).val();


         window.location.href="SelectTest.html?type="+sel;

        });

});



</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="e"> 
<div data-role="header"> 
<h1>Test</h1> 
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="toi">

<div>
<label for="lang">Select Language</label>
<select name="language" id="lang">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="hi">Hindi</option>
<option value="sp">Spanish</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
</select>
</div>



<div id="main">

</div>
</div>
</div> 
<div data-role="footer"> 
<h4>Test</h4> 
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me on Chrome, so yeah, it might be an issue on mobile

Comment: Is it? Even i'm trying in chrome but no luck. Is the option getting changed even after page refresh. For me every time only English option is getting selected

Comment: It works for every option. Maybe you have something else going on in the page?

Comment: hmm i don't undertand why it's not working for me..anyways after doing refresh as suggest by Jonathan it worked for me. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the jquery mobile docs:

> If you manipulate a select via
>   JavaScript, you must call the refresh
>   method on it to update the visual
>   styling. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> var myselect = $("select#foo");
> myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
> myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
> ```

So basically you just need to call refresh on it. Does this help?

For your code you can chain it like this

```
$('#lang').val(aval).selectmenu("refresh");
```

Comment: No problem! I had the same issue with Sliders... the syntax is slightly different for sliders. I believe it's `.slider("refresh")`.